# How to fetch this JSON values in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I am confused how to fetch this JSON values, I have tried but I am not sure about it :

This is my JSON url :

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=d7b900681c37193223281142bd919019
```

This is how i am just trying to fetch json values.

```
JSONObject ishu=new JSONObject(String url);//URL OF MY JSON!!
JSONObject COORD=ishu.getJSONObject("coord");
String LON=1.getString("lon");
String LAT=1.getString("lat");

JSONObject ishu1=ishu.getJSONObject("weather");
JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray(jsonStr);

for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
{
  JSONObject jsonobject=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
  String id=jsonobject.getString("id");
  String main=jsonobject.getString("main");
  Stirng description=jsonobject.getString("description");
  String icon=jsonobject.getString("icon");
}

JSONObject ishu2=ishu.getJSONObject("base");
String MAIN=ishu.getString("main");
String TEMP=MAIN.getString("temp");
String PRESSURE=MAIN.getString("pressure");
String HUMIDITY=MAIN.getString("humidity");
String TEMP_MIN=MAIN.getString("temp_min");
String TEMP_MAX=MAIN.getString("temp_max");

JSONObject WIND=ishu.getJSONObject("wind");
String SPEED=WIND.getString("speed");
String DEG=WIND.getString("deg");
String GUST=ishu.getString("gust");

JSONObject ishu4=ishu.getJSONObject("rain");
JSONObject 1H=ishu4.getJSONObject("1h");

JSONObject ishu5=ishu.getJSONObject("clouds");
String ALL =ishu5.getString("all");

JSONObject ishu6=ishu.getJSONObject("dt");
String SYS=ishu.getString("sys");
String TYPE=SYS.getString("type");
String ID=SYS.getString("id");
String MESSAGE=SYS.getString("message");
String COUNTRY=SYS.getString("country");
String SUNRISE=SYS.getString("sunrise");
String SUNSET=SYS.getString("sunset");

JSONObject ishu7=ishu.getJSONObject("id");
JSONObject ishu8=ishu.getJSONObject("name");
JSONObject ishu9=ishu.getJSONObject("cod");
```

Comment: do you get any errors? What's the problem that you are facing?

Comment: this depends on which library you actually are using.

Comment: `JSONObject` will not fetch data from the URL, it will try to parse the URL as JSON not the data requested from the URL. But given the fact that `new JSONObject(String url)` isn't valid Java ...

Comment: i just wanna know that whether i am doing right or not i have just written this on my notepad not in android studio.

Comment: download json data first  then do                                                 JSONObject ishu=new JSONObject("the jsonString you get");

Answer (score 0):

Download your JSon file using RestFul service (Default HttpUrlConnection / Volly Library) and give the downloaded String to above you code.

Its better use any parsing tool then doing it manually.
http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

GSon is simple to use and it is from Google.

As simple as below

```
ModelClass object = new Gson().fromJson(JsonString, ModelClass.class);
```

Comment: Actually my question is just check whether i am using (JSONObject) and (JSONArray)  on right place or not,dont go on deep as i am just open my json url and start fetching the values using JSONObject and JSONArray,i am not writing on android studio rightnow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you firstly need to get the response from the api.openweathermap.com.

```
 URL url= new URL("<your url here>");
 HttpURLConnection connnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
 InputStream is = connnection.getInputStream();
```

read from `is` your JSON, and after that you can do `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(<your string here>);`

Comment: Actually my question is just check whether i am using (JSONObject) and (JSONArray)  on right place or not,dont go on deep as i am just open my json url and start fetching the values using JSONObject and JSONArray,i am not writing on android studio rightnow.

Comment: @ishumishra Can you post the example of json?

Comment: do you want example of json?I am not getting what you are trying to confer?

Comment: @ishumishra, then I don't understand what the question is about

Comment: @madatx..Actually this is the link for json http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=d7b900681c37193223281142bd919019      I am just trying to know whether i am using JSONArray or JSONObject on right place or not?